# How to get executables using premake?

Tags: c++, build, g++, premake

sorry if this question is too naive but i'm new to using build tools as previously i used visual studio's default build tool( just right click and select build ).

Now i am working with linux, and want to develop a cross platform application.I'm now using premake as i've heard that it is "insanely" cross platform compatible. I made the premake.lua but i am unable to find what should be the appropriate name for the toolset parameter if i want to compile using g++( i believe it stands for the compiler ) in the command:

premake --target toolset

I checked the link:
http://premake.sourceforge.net/what_is_premake and many others they give the toolset name for gcc, code::blocks etc but not for g++.Secondly even if i give toolset name as cb-ow, for Cde::Blocks. I don't get the executables, i get the .cbw files

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to specify a toolset at all. Just do:

```
premake4 gmake
```

It will use the default toolset (which is GCC is on Linux).

Oh, I should also mention that you are using Premake 3, which is *way* out of date at this point. Check out the 4.x stuff here: http://industriousone.com/premake.